# Load page content in another page

Tags: language-agnostic

Take a look at the signup section over here:

http://www.istockphoto.com/istock_login

Can you explain me please how can that moving box have been created?
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide more info? Are you talking about the image rotater in the background?

Comment: the container over the page are u talking about ? if yes, try this plugin: http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if what your talking about is the box that shows up when you click on the login but, that is called lightbox. It's Javascript & Jquery that gets whatever content you want and makes a "frame" that overlays the rest of your page. There are lots of pre-made plugins witch if you want to replicate that effect I would sugest you to use because they are simple and easy.

http://www.fancybox.net/
http://www.lightbox.com.br/
http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/
http://www.shadowbox-js.com/